# Grails geb getting parameters from commandline

Tags: grails, geb

I am writing my ui tests with geb in grails .
I want to start the tests from command line with maven. This works fine.
My command: 
mvn -Dtest=CheckMenuLinks test

Now I want to pass some parameters for tests from commandline. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: 
I just add some parameter like: 
-Dmytest=myparameter

I can use this parameter in gebconfig with:

```
System.getProperty("mytest")
```